# Encoding charcters like "+" with QUrlQuery

Tags: qt, post, encoding

I am trying to encode POST Http queries using [QUrlQuery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurlquery.html). Reading at several places, this seems to be the solution:

```
QUrlQuery query;
query.addQueryItem("name","value");
QString queryString = query.query(QUrl::FullyEncoded);
```

but this code:

```
QUrlQuery query;
query.addQueryItem("calc","x+x");
qDebug() << query.query(QUrl::FullyEncoded);
```

Outputs:

```
"calc=x+x"
```

So the "+" did not get encoded. Why? And how do I properly encode an arbitrary String for POST parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QUrlQuery is only part of QUrl.

If by encoding you mean percent encoding, then you can do it with code like this:

```
qDebug() << QUrl::toPercentEncoding(query.toString());
```